# what causes "insufficient karma" error when committing to cvs

Tags: cvs, commit

When using Eclipse to commit a change to a file to a branch of a project in CVS, it fails, and the following is in CVS Console in Eclipse (with specifics stripped out)

```
***
cvs ci -m "comment for the commit" -l "/PROJECT/path/to/file/fileName.java"
    **** Access denied: Insufficient Karma (userName|PROJECT/path/to/file|branchName)
    cvs commit: Pre-commit check failed
    cvs [commit aborted]: correct above errors first!
The server reported an error while performing the "cvs commit" command. (took 0:00.209)
   Error: PROJECT: cvs commit: Pre-commit check failed
   Error: PROJECT: cvs [commit aborted]: correct above errors first!
***
```

I was able to commit successfully 2 days ago (using Eclipse).

What is Karma in CVS, and what does this error message mean?

Comment: http://drupal.star.bnl.gov/STAR/comp/sofi/tutorials/cvs#Karma ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was an updated `$CVSROOT/CVSROOT/avail` on the CVS server file which removed commit privileges. Thanks to @Jarry for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that error message when trying to commit to a read-only repository directory. Usually it was when the branch was ready for a release or merge.